# How to import azure devops artifacts and upload to GitHub

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to import all artifacts from azure devops portal and need to upload to GitHub. i am windows laptop .

is there any process to import azure devops artifacts and to upload Github.

I have this task from manager but before i didn't this kind of task .